# NotificationListenerService gets killed but never restarted

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

Hi all i'm having troubles with an app that I'm developing. I make use of NotificationListenerService, prompt the user to set the Notification permission from the menu and all works flawlessly. But when I update my app, or when my service gets killed it, for unknown reasons, doesn't restart.
In `onCreate()` I retain a reference to the service with `instance = this;` that I use to determine if my service is running from other classes.

This is some methods in `onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification notification)` that extends NotificationListenerService:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    if (MyOtherService.hasInstance()) {
        Log.v(TAG, "onNotificationPosted called by system");
        int count_debug = 1;
        for (StatusBarNotificationListenerInterface listener : toBeNotified) {
            if(listener != null) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Loop call #" + count_debug++);
                listener.onNotificationHotAdded(sbn);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // MyOtherService isn't running. Does nothing but clearing toBeNotified list.
        toBeNotified.clear();
        Log.v(TAG, "onNotificationPosted: MyOtherService is stopped ");
    }
}

public static void registerForNotifications(StatusBarNotificationListenerInterface listener) {
    if (!toBeNotified.contains(listener)) {
        Log.v(TAG, listener.getClass().getCanonicalName() + " added to toBeNotified list");
        toBeNotified.add(listener);
    }
}
```

NOTE: MyOtherService extends DreamService and just register itself calling the `registerForNotifications()` method.

In the `MyNotificationListener` I override `onStartCommand` returning `START_STICKY`

I'm really going crazy with this stuff being killed almost at each update.

Comment: What are you returning from `MyOtherService`'s `onStartCommand()`?

Comment: Edit: it is a dreamservice extension. So it's a class that's an hybrid between a service and an activity. It's working fine but the one that I posted doesn't

Comment: This seems to be a known issue, see here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=62811

Comment: found that the best way to trigger this bug is to install packages through adb using `adb install -l -r package.apk` the -l forward-locks the app and almost always triggers this bug.